# Will a self signed code-signing certificate get rid of "Unknown Publisher" warnings?

Tags: self-signed, code-signing-certificate, security-warning

Will a self signed code-signing certificate get rid of "Unknown Publisher" warnings?

What will be the effect of using a self signed certificate with regards to warnings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I create self-signed certificate in Java which will be automatically trusted by web browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301297/can-i-create-self-signed-certificate-in-java-which-will-be-automatically-trusted). While you didn't mention OS or language, the information is equally applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me.
For local testing, yes that is possible.

1. Right click the installer and go to *Properties*.
2. Click on the *Digital Signatures* tab.
3. Under *Signature list* select the signer and click *Details*
4. Click *View Certificate*
5. Click *Install Certificate...*, then *Next >*
6. Select *Place all certificates in the following store* radio button
7. Click *Browse* and select *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*
8. Click OK and click *Next >*, and then *Finish*.
9. A Security Warning will appear informing you that you're doing this at your own risk.

If you want to remove this certificate you can do that by going to certmgr.msc and removing the certificate located under **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**

Comment: This does not address Windows Defender's SmartScreen warnings, but does address executable properties Digital Signatures tab.

Answer (score 2):

You will still get warnings like untrusted signing authority when using self signed certificates. You usually just self sign on your own servers to test SSL. You don't want to self sign SSL on a production server.

Answer (score 2):

No, a self-signed won't work for that. You'll have to get a code signing cert from a real Ca, see http://codesigning.ksoftware.net or http://www.verisign.com (and there are many more).

Answer (score 0):

If you install your self-signed certificate into the Root Certification Authorities store, you will not get "Unknown Publisher" warnings.