# Can I run a command before the setup.msi?

Tags: visual-studio, inno-setup, setup-project, user-account-control

I have a desktop application and its installer project produces two files in the `Release` folder: let's call them `setup.exe` and `setup.msi`.

In the post build event I sign the `setup.msi` with a self signed certificate. Then my final installation batch is composed of three steps

1. Adding user store certificate with a `start.cmd` (or `start.exe`)
2. Running the `setup.exe`. Notice that the important thing is that it shows a user account control for a **verified** author with my name and surname.
3. Removing (with a `stop.cmd` or `stop.exe`) the certificate at point 1 for security reasons/best practices since it is self signed

Now I'm perfectly fine with this solution, I only wished to include the commands 1 and 3 inside the `setup.exe` if it was possible in a standard way.

What I have tried to do is to define the `start.exe` and `stop.exe` as custom actions. In that case I only have the two files `setup.exe` and `setup.msi` but unfortunately I get an **unkown** publisher. I guess it is obviously because the custom actions go inside the `.msi` and not in the `setup.exe`. But I'm not an expert of installer projects so someone might suggest a better and standard solution.

**Alternative approach**

Is that something that I could much more easily do by switching to Inno Setup and maybe as suggested in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493416/how-to-run-a-file-before-setup-with-inno-setup#comment8099659_3493573)?

### References

- [How do I create a self-signed certificate for code signing on
  Windows? - Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201277/11323942)
- [Answer about certmgr.msc - Will a self signed code-signing
  certificate get rid of “Unknown Publisher” warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40039537/11323942)
- [Sign tools downloadable from github](https://github.com/3gstudent/signtools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated answer

Sorry, I've tested my original answer below and it is "wrong" in a sense:

actually I get a single click installer but then the Windows operating system anticipates the user account control before such single click installer and it shows an unknown publisher, which defeats the purpose of point 1 (and 3).

So, short, updated answer: it is impossible(*) to do that in a standard single-click exe, like the ones produced by the SFX module mention below.

(**Note ***): though it is doable by compiling a custom C# code and by adding files to the `Resources.resx`, for example `_7zr.exe`, etc... like in this example:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace selfextractinstaller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file_path_7zr = @"_7zr.exe";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file_path_7zr, FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] pgm_bytes = Properties.Resources._7zr;
                fs.Write(pgm_bytes, 0, (int)pgm_bytes.Length);
            }
            string file_path_config = @"config.txt";
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file_path_config, false))
            {
                sw.Write(Properties.Resources.config);
            }
            string file_path_7zSD = @"_7zSD.sfx";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(file_path_7zSD, FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] pgm_bytes = Properties.Resources._7zSD;
                fs.Write(pgm_bytes, 0, (int)pgm_bytes.Length);
            }
            Process.Start(file_path_7zr, "b");
        }
    }
}
```

A similar code can be actually used as a self extracting installer that is *not elevated* and *does not require the UAC*!

### Further Readings

- [How does Windows decide whether to display the UAC prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096706/how-does-windows-decide-whether-to-display-the-uac-prompt)
- [How do I add a manifest to an executable using mt.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423492/how-do-i-add-a-manifest-to-an-executable-using-mt-exe)

### Original answer

In absence of other answers, I'll proceed with a [SFX module for installers](https://superuser.com/a/42792), by packaging all the three `.exe` at points 1-3 (plus an `install_all.bat` running them in sequence) into a self extracting installer, that will automatically extract all the needed files (certificate included) and finally run the `install_all.bat`